# Reason for a mysterious padding breaking my design?

Tags: javascript, twitter, padding, alignment

I have been trying to wrap my head around this issue for the past few hours but with no success. If you look at this [page](http://ftfranes.com/mliad2/).

On the left side, where its titled "Latest Tweets", there is a mysterious left-padding to the list of tweets. I can assure you that I have not added any styling to it to have that padding... not to my knowledge anyway.

For a past few hours ago, before I made major changes around the page, it looked perfect. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTRUJ.png) of how it should be aligned.

[image: screenshot]

Its 11.15pm, I'm tired and I want to watch Game of Thrones. Can someone kindly assist me in solving this issue so that I can call it a night?

Comment: need some recent tweets before I try to debug ;)

Comment: Check the UL/LI margin/paddings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `margin-left: 15px;` on `.projects li`.

That is what causes the move to the right...

Perhaps you added it for the list of videos, but it is affecting the list of the tweets since both are under the `projects` element.

Add `.projects .sidebar_left li{margin-left:0}` to fix it..

---

**Update**

or better yet, since you already have a rule for them `#twitter_update_list li` add the `margin-left:0` to that.

Comment: There comes a time in the night when your mind stops functioning properly. Basically, I uploaded an old stylesheet and was reviewing a new one. Nevertheless, cheers for this, I'll accept this as the answer within a few minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Gaby beat me to posting the answer, but you could have found it yourself inspecting the elements using Google Chrome for example - you can click an element and it tells you what style the element has, like this:

```
.projects li {
width: 202px;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

Better yet, you appear to be able to test style changes LIVE.  Pretty cool, actually.

Comment: Cheers for the info buddy, while I will acccept Gaby's answer because he was first, I still appreciate your input.